Fréchet subdifferential for weakly convex functions on Hilbert spaces
Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space. The Fréchet subdifferential of a function $f\colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is the set-valued operator $\partial f:\mathcal{H} \rightrightarrows \mathcal{H}$ given by
\begin{align*}
    \partial f (x) =
    \begin{cases}
        \{u\in\mathcal{H} : \displaystyle{\liminf_{y\rightarrow x}} \frac{f(y)-f(x) - \langle{u,y-x}\rangle }{\lVert{y-x}\rVert}\geq 0 \} & \text{if } |f(x)| < + \infty, \\
        \emptyset & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
for each $x\in\mathcal{H}$. If $f$ is Fréchet differentiable at a point $x\in\mathcal{H}$, then $\partial f(x) = \{\nabla f(x)\}$. Moreover, if $f$ is proper (i.e., $-\infty \notin f(\mathcal{H})$ and $\exists y \in \mathcal{H}$ such that $f(y)< \infty$) and convex, the Fréchet subdifferential becomes the convex subdifferential, i.e, $\partial f(x) = \{u \in \mathcal{H} : \forall y \in \mathcal{H}\, f(y) \geq f(x) + \langle{u,y-x}\rangle \}$ for each $x\in\mathcal{H}$.
Now, suppose that $f\colon \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ is proper and $\rho$-weakly convex, i.e., $f+\frac{\rho}{2}\lVert\cdot\rVert^2$ is convex for some $\rho>0$. My question is: What can we say about the Féchet subdifferential $\partial f(x)$? I'm particularly interested in nonemptyness, closeness, and convexity. What if $f$ also is lower semicontinuous.
I can't seem to find answers to these questions in Clarke, Mordukhovich, and Rockafellar & Wets' books.
Random thought: Are weakly convex functions locally Lipschitz continuous (on the interior of their effective domain)?
Claim I have seen in the literature: The Féchet subdifferential and Clarke subdifferential coincide for weakly convex functions.
Conjecture: In the weakly convex case we have that
\begin{align*}
\partial f(x) = \partial( f + \frac{\rho}{2}\lVert\cdot\rVert^2 )(x) - \{\rho x\}
\end{align*}
for each $x\in\mathcal{H}$ such that $|f(x)| < + \infty$, where $\partial( f + \frac{\rho}{2}\lVert\cdot\rVert^2 )$ reduces to the convex subdifferential.

This is the sum rule for the Frechet subdifferential (involving a Frechet differentiable function), it has nothing to do with weak convexity.

Let $f:X \to \bar {\mathbb R}$ be finite at $x$, $g:X \to \mathbb R$ be Frechet differentiable at $x$. Then
$$
\partial (f + g)(x) = \partial f(x) + g'(x).
$$

Proof.
By Frechet differentiability of $g$, we know
$$
\lim_{y\to x} \frac{  g(y) -  g(x) - \langle g'(x),y-x\rangle }{\|y-x\|} = 0.
$$
Take $u \in X'$.
Then
$$
\liminf_{y\to x} \frac{ f(y) + g(y) - f(x)  - g(x) - \langle u-g'(x),y-x\rangle }{\|y-x\|} \ge 0.
$$
is equivalent to
$$
\liminf_{y\to x} \frac{ f(y)  - f(x)   - \langle u,y-x\rangle }{\|y-x\|} \ge 0.
$$
This proves $\partial (f + g)(x) = \partial f(x) + g'(x)$.
